# Why can $ϕ(p)$ be Fourier expanded to $ψ(x)$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, conventions, fourier-transform

I know the Fourier transform is $$
F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} \,d x
$$
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{i \omega x} \,d \omega,
$$
but in quantum mechanics the momentum wave function $\phi(p)$ and positional wave function $\psi(x)$ are related by
$$
\psi(x, t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(p, t) \mathrm{e}^{+\mathrm{i} p x / \hbar} d p
$$
$$
\phi(p, t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x, t) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} p x / \hbar} d x.
$$
My question are:

- Why can $\phi(p)$ be Fourier expanded in $\psi(x)$?
- where did the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}}$ come from? Why not $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$？

Comment: All $L^2$-normalizable functions can be Fourier transformed. The factors of $\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$ is simply a matter of convention. Different textbooks use slightly different definitions for the Fourier transform. This will not be the first place you find such differences in definition.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265299/the-2-pi-in-the-definition-of-the-fourier-transform)

Answer (score 6):

You are just asking notation. The Fourier transform comes with a choice of where and how to put the $2\pi$, unless you start with the most mathematically natural version.

First, you should rewrite your transformation with the usual symbols, $k$ instead of $\omega:$
$
\begin{align}
\tag1f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}&\int F(k)\,e^{+ikx}\,\mathrm dk\\
\tag2F(k)=&\int f(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm dx
\end  {align}
$
Now substitute $p=\hslash k$
$
\begin{align}
\tag3f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int F(p)\,e^{+ipx/\hslash}\,\frac{\mathrm dp}\hslash=\frac1{2\pi\hslash}&\int F(p)\,e^{+ipx/\hslash}\,\mathrm dp\\
\tag4F(p)=&\int f(x)\,e^{-ipx/\hslash}\,\mathrm dx
\end  {align}
$
Finally, let $\psi(x,t)=\sqrt{2\pi\hslash}f(x,t)$ and $\phi(p,t)=F(p,t)$ and you get the version you want at the end.

---

The most mathematically natural version of the Fourier transform is actually
$
\begin{align}
\tag5f( t )&=\int F(\nu)\,e^{+2\pi i\nu t}\,\mathrm d\nu\\
\tag6F(\nu)&=\int f( t )\,e^{-2\pi i\nu t}\,\mathrm d t
\end  {align}
$
Which you should prove to yourself from considering the infinite limit of the discrete Fourier transform. This is the form with no weirdness happening. It is the definition of $\omega=2\pi\nu$ that leads to the appearance of $2\pi$ in Equation (1)

Comment: lol, the other versions are equivalent. Why do you say "mathematically precise version"?

Comment: @TobiasFünke - ya, that was funny. They started by saying "its just notation" and ended with giving the "most precise" notation.

Comment: I dont know the correct word for what I wanted to point out, which is that, we usually start with the function in position representation, and so we have freedom to define its Fourier representation, but as you see in my answer, any other choice of where the $2\pi$ goes other than Equation (5&6) or Equation (1&2) results in having to redefine the function in position representation, and that is just unsavoury. Equation (5&6) is the most illuminating, the closest approach to the discrete Fourier transform, that explains why all these factors arise. That privileges it.

Comment: It is not. You cannot link from discrete Fourier to the other alternatives without suddenly introducing arbitrary changes.

Comment: The requirement that the continuous Fourier transform be linked to the discrete one is certainly a personal preference. If you consider that an important link, then your final definition is a natural one. Otherwise, it's not.

Answer (score 3):

For your first bullet point of why $\phi(p)$ (which itself is a Fourier transform of $\psi(x)$) can be ‘Fourier-expanded’ in terms of $\psi(x)$, the answer is by [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem). This is actually a pretty non-trivial theorem requiring a lot of care with the analysis of interchanging limiting operations (‘regularization argument’ to interchange a limit with the integral i.e Dominated convergence theorem, followed by swapping two integrals, i.e Fubini’s theorem, then followed by undoing the regularization, i.e undoing DCT) and careful hypotheses on the class of functions involved. You may find some quick ‘proofs’ involving Dirac deltas but that just beats around the bush and doesn’t establish anything properly yet (even if we assume our functions belong to the Schwartz class (i.e ‘as nice as can be’)).

For your next question about constants, the only real answer is that you just need one convention and be consistent. Relating two different conventions is simply an annoying, but elementary matter of changing variables in integration by a simple scaling factor. But, let me mention some generalities and some pros/cons of various conventions. For convenience throughout, we work with $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, the space of [Schwartz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). For each $c\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and each $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, let us define the ‘geneal-scale Fourier transform’ $\Phi_{c,\lambda}$ defined by setting for each function $f\in\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)$,
\begin{align}
\Phi_{c,\lambda}[f](\xi):=c\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x\cdot\xi}\,dx.
\end{align}
Then, we have the following properties:

- The inverse is $(\Phi_{c,\lambda})^{-1}[g](x)=\frac{1}{c\left(2\pi/\lambda\right)^n}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}g(\xi)e^{i\lambda x\cdot\xi}\,d\xi$. Again, this is due to the Fourier inversion theorem; it is often proved with a specific set of constants for $c,\lambda$, and I just derived this using appropriate change of variables.
- If we consider the $L^2$ norm, we have $\|\Phi_{c,\lambda}(f)\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}=|c|\cdot \left|\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\right|^{n/2}\|f\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}$.
- For the inverse transform, the $L^2$ norms are related as $\|(\Phi_{c,\lambda})^{-1}(g)\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}=\frac{1}{|c|\cdot\left|2\pi/\lambda\right|^{n/2}}\|g\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}$.
- For convolutions, we have $\Phi_{c,\lambda}(f*g)=\frac{1}{c(2\pi/\lambda)^n}\Phi_{c,\lambda}(f)\cdot \Phi_{c,\lambda}(g)$.
- For any multiindex $\alpha$, the derivative is transformed as $\Phi_{c,\lambda}(\partial^{\alpha}f)(\xi)=(-i\lambda \xi)^{\alpha}\cdot \Phi_{c,\lambda}(f)(\xi)$.

So, morally speaking, the ‘general-scale Fourier transform’ $\Phi_{c,\lambda}$, as expected is such that if you want to invert, then replace $i$ with $-i$ in the exponential, and on top of that, you need to correct by a suitable factor. Next, $\Phi_{c,\lambda}$ is almost an isometry, except for some scalar multiple, and the same thing with its inverse. Finally, it sends convolutions to pointwise products, but again there’s the caveat of a suitable factor. Finally, it sends derivatives to multiplication (again with a suitable factor). Now, I’ll talk about some of the common conventions and pros and cons.

---

**Convention 1: $(c,\lambda)=(1,2\pi)$.**

I’ll call the operator $\mathcal{F}$ in this case. This is my personal favorite convention (and also I believe the preferred one in harmonic analysis) because I think it has the simplest properties of all and requires the least brain power to remember (and it’s also the first one I learnt). We have

- $(\mathcal{F}f)(\xi):=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\,dx$.
- The inverse is obtained by simply replacing $i$ with $-i$: $(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g))(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}g(\xi)e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\,d\xi$.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is an isometry for the $L^2$ norm, i.e $\|\mathcal{F}f\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}=\|f\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)}$, and likewise with the invese.
- $\mathcal{F}$ sends convolutions to products: $\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\cdot \mathcal{F}(g)$.
- $\mathcal{F}(\partial^{\alpha}f)(\xi)=(-2\pi i \xi)^{\alpha}\cdot \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$.

So, you just once and for all stick a $2\pi$ in the exponential, and you never worry about for $99\%$ of the time. The only time you’ll pick up an extra factor is when you take the Fourier transform of a derivative.
I personally rather have only one place to worry about $2\pi$’s rather than a bunch of places. But hey, people’s tastes vary, and this is particularly so if you’re going to be dealing with derivatives often because then you will want to avoid the $2\pi$’s there.

---

**Convention 2. $(c,\lambda)=(1,1)$**.

I have nothing much to say about this convention; it has funny factors all over the place, and its only ‘saving grace’ is that the forward map is easy to remember as the integral is simply $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx$ (and sometimes, people replace the $-i$ with $+i$ instead) and that for derivatives, there are no weird factors. But I guess this convention is common in the electrical engineering side?

---

**Convention 3. $(c,\lambda)=\left(\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{n/2}},\frac{1}{\hbar}\right)$**.

This is essentially the convention used in QM. This is a nice convention because the forward and inverse map are related to each other simply by replacing $i$ with $-i$, and the prefactor in both cases simplifies to $\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar )^{n/2}}$. But still, it’s not perfect because the $L^2$ norm is not preserved, and Fourier transforms of convolutions pick up an extra factor as well. Fourier transform of derivative is multiplication by $(-i\xi/\hbar)^{\alpha}$.

So, this convention for my taste, is still pretty annoying and not ideal at all (too many places still have weird constants). It is only if you decide to work in units where $\hbar=1$ where I can see the benefit, because now the forward and inverse Fourier transforms become $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{\mp i x\cdot\xi}\,dx$ which is easy to remember and Fourier transform of derivative is simply $\Phi(\partial^{\alpha} f)(\xi)=(-i\xi)^{\alpha}\cdot \Phi(f)(\xi)$. Also, one deals often with differential operators in QM (e.g the momentum operator) so working wanting to simplify the Fourier transform of derivatives is understandable.